# Looking for a way to persist user data

Tags: android, kotlin

I need my users to be able to enter an API key in a "Setup" fragment and I need to use this API key in various other places such as other Fragments, Activities, Workers.

It is my understanding so far that getSharedPreferences is designed for this sort of purpose, much like the NSUserDefaults under iOS: save something somewhere, get it elsewhere.

Yet I can't seem to get the getSharedPreferences thing to work, I've had it initialized throughout the app with MainActivity.context but it always loses the data (the API key)

I am using ModelPreferencesManager https://gist.github.com/malwinder-s/bf2292bcdda73d7076fc080c03724e8a

I have an ApplicationState class as follows:

```
public class ApplicationState : Application() {
    companion object {
        // ...
        lateinit var mContext: Context
        var api_key : String = "undefined"
        // ...
    }
        fun save(){
            Log.e("ApplicationState", "save")
            ModelPreferencesManager.with(mContext)
            ModelPreferencesManager.put(api_key , key: "api_key_identifier")
        }

        fun load(){
            Log.e("ApplicationState", "load")
            ModelPreferencesManager.with(mContext)
            api_key = ModelPreferencesManager.get<String>(key: "api_key_identifier") ?: "not read"
        }
}
```

First, I store the application context on the first Activity (before anything else):

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        // ...
        ApplicationState.mContext = applicationContext
        // ...
    }
}
```

I now expect to be able to save the api_key as follows:

```
ApplicationState.api_key = "blablah" // from some input in a random fragment
ApplicationState.save()
```

And to load it later:

```
ApplicationState.load()
var api_key = ApplicationState.api_key // in some activity or random fragment or worker
```

However it doesn't produce the expected result, the api_key is not saved (or loaded? can't figure out)

I have also tried using a JSON file but still no luck, looks like it either doesn't write/read or just gets deleted for some reason.

I could use a helping hand from someone more experienced as I am new to Android development and can't seem to find my way through these intricacies

Comment: `SharedPreferences` are typically used for (as the name implies) user _preferences_, in your case, if this value is really something important, you might want to consider something like a database instead or looking at encrypted shared prefs, although this isn't really a big concern if it's just a simple app you're making

Comment: When you say _database_ I'm assuming you're referring to something like SQLite or Room, and not a remote database?

Comment: Room is an abstraction layer built over sqlite, so yes, sqlite

Comment: Gracias, going to play with it now. You wouldn't happen to know a reliable key-value or document store? I'm just saving "documents" as opposed to structured data

Comment: that's a complicated question. it depends on what you care about. if it's a test/internal app, i don't see a real issue with shared prefs (it's key-value), it's simplest to get started with, but i think you just need to find a simpler implementation somewhere than what you're doing here. alternatively, if you want a more robust solution, a db will work but is more complicated to get set up. all my personal opinion

Comment: there's also a newer api, i haven't used this myself yet, but you're welcome to try out [datastore](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore) as well

Comment: It’s a kiosk app that displays some infotainment-style content in a few activities with a simple nav graph. It connects to a remote service over a REST API that needs a key to be passed, the key is device-specific and I’m scanning it from a QR code on first run, then supposed to pick it up from wherever when needed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are doing with your ModelPreferencesManager.

But this is the standard way to save something in preferences.

```
    val sharedPref = requireContext().getSharedPreferences(keyPrefIdentifier, 
    Context.MODE_PRIVATE) //get shared preferences
    val editor = sharedPref.edit() //make modifications to shared preferences
    editor.putString("userApiKeyIdent", "theActualKey")
    editor.apply() //save shared preferences persitent.
```

This is how you read them again.

```
    val sharedPref = requireContext().getSharedPreferences(keyPrefIdentifier, 
    Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val apiKey = sharedPref.getString("userApiKeyIdent", "defaultValue")
```

Edit: You are saving the api key as the identifiery for the preference. But get it as "api key "

It should look like this

```
    fun save(){
        Log.e("ApplicationState", "save")
        ModelPreferencesManager.with(mContext)
        ModelPreferencesManager.put("api_key ", api_key) //like this
    }
```

Comment: OP is doing this inside a class extending from application, so you probably don't need `requireContext`

Comment: I tried it but it won't run without a context. Maybe I just misunderstand how this all works.